# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly variable in math equation

Tags: python, int

i am new to python but i tried to put DogAge into a math equation, still not working

```
Animal = input("dog or cat? ")

if Animal == "dog":
    DogAge = int(input("how old is you dog? "))
else:
    CatAge = int(input("how old is your cat? "))

if DogAge == 1:
    print("your dog's age is 11")
elif DogAge == 2:
    print("your dog's age is 22")
else:
    print("your dog's age is " + (DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22))
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: @RachelGallen this has nothing to do with html or radiobuttons.

Comment: Are you aware that `DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22` is not `(DogAge - 2) * 4 + 22` but `DogAge + 14`?

Comment: ...since it is evaluated as `DogAge - (2 * 4) + 22` because, by default, multiplication has higher operator precedence than addition and subtract unless that's overridden with parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

The error points exactly what's going wrong. Change this:

```
print("your dog's age is " + (DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22))
```

To this:

```
print("your dog's age is " + str(DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22))
```

You can't concatenate a string object with an integer.

Comment: Could also, more simply, use `print("your dog's age is", DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
print("your dog's age is {0}".format((DogAge - 2) * 4 + 22))
```

(assuming that you want to calculate `(DogAge-2) * 4 + 22`, not `DogAge + 14`).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider reorganising your code differently, to separate out the calculation of the dogs age and the actual printing of the value.

As it's possible then to refactor that code into a function later on, if it gets more complicated.

```
Animal = input("dog or cat? ")

if Animal == "dog":
    DogAge = int(input("how old is you dog? "))
else:
    CatAge = int(input("how old is your cat? ")) 

if DogAge == 1:
    calculated_dogs_age = 11
elif DogAge == 2:
    calculated_dogs_age = 22
else:
    calculated_dogs_age = DogAge - 2 * 4 + 22

print("your dog's age is {0:d}".format(calculated_dogs_age))
```

Comment: Gosh - I wasn't going to change too much of the OPs code - so that it wasn't recognisable by them - It's a fine balance and difficult to know when to stop. You only have to look at the way SO formats the OP's code to feel quesy.